# Ubuntu 14.04 syslog showing @@@@ for long time period

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, syslog

My Ubuntu Server wasn't accessible for a long time, only after restarting the server I could access it again. I have checked the syslog file which shows something like @@@@@@@@@@@@@ from last night until the point I restarted the system. What is it?